# better randomization with php

Tags: php

How random is rand(), and is there a solution for generating *more* random numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by "how random"? As to your second comment, `rand()` generates exactly one random number - to generate more, call it more than once. Could you clarify what it is you're trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

How about `mt_rand()`, which uses the Mersenne Twister. It should generate random numbers up to the size of an int. (use `mt_getrandmax()` to get the maximum value).

Answer (score 2):

There *is* a better random number generator (which is referenced in the '`see also`' section of the documentation of [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php), by the way): [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Comment: Slower - really? docs say its 4 times faster: "... which will produce random numbers four times faster than what the average libc `rand()` provides."

Comment: Woops, sorry. Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/mt_rand

is better than rand()

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function from the **mt_rand** notes in the function documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php#83358